# display none / remove style for asp.net code behind not working

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I've got a button on my page in code behind I do this:

`btnSaveLineItems.Style.Add("display", "none");`

But later I want to show that button so I tried this:

`btnSaveLineItems.Style.Clear();`

This doesnt appear to reshow the button...
The html markup in the beginning has a "style=display:none;" in the beginning of the page..
and it maintains that style even though I try to remove it?

When my page first starts up I have this:

`btnSaveLineItems.Style["display"] = "none";`

This renders like the following in HTML:

`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveLineItems" value="Save" id="MainContent_btnSaveLineItems" title="Save changes?" style="border-color:#4B6C9E;border-style:Solid;display:none;" />`

Then an event happens (selected index changed event of a drop down box) where I then do this:

`btnSaveLineItems.Style["display"] = "";`

I've also tried:

`btnSaveLineItems.Style["display"] = "block";`

and both render the same HTML:

`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveLineItems" value="Save" id="MainContent_btnSaveLineItems" title="Save changes?" style="border-color:#4B6C9E;border-style:Solid;display:none;" />`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can  remove that style in this way:

```
 btnSaveLineItems.Style["display"] = "";
```

or

```
btnSaveLineItems.Style.Remove("display");
```

**Edit**:

> That doesnt work for me either...I wonder if it is because of the drop
>   down list box is inside of an update panel and this button is outside
>   of the updatepanel?

Yes, you can only update the content of the current `UpdatePanel` in an asynchronous postback by default. The easiest would be to put your Button in another `UpdatePanel` and add the `DropDownList` as  `AsyncPostBackTrigger`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSaveLineItems" Text="click me" runat="server" />
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" />
     </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me either...I wonder if it is because of the drop down list box is inside of an update panel and this button is outside of the updatepanel?

Comment: The first line you gave cannot be valid javascript

Comment: @TimSchmelter if you are manipulating dom, it's javascript. If this is some other language that generates the actual javascript that does the job, then it's fine. Is it?

Comment: no matter what I do the rendered html appears as  `<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveLineItems" value="Save" id="MainContent_btnSaveLineItems" title="Save changes?" style="border-color:#4B6C9E;border-style:Solid;display:none;" />`

Comment: @TimSchmelter it looks like assigning to function call is not valid in that language either ? ;) I removed my downvote no hard feelings.

Comment: Tim right that is what I was thinking - I have so many issues when it comes to updatepanels, is this normal and is it ok to be adding all of these updatepanels everywhere?  It just seems so wrong.

Comment: If the above is your code (two seperate update panels) you can't update the content of Panel1 from inside the events of Panel2. Also, if this is being done on the code behind why are you not using .Visble=true and .Visible=false?

Comment: @oJM86o: Add all into one UpdatePanel that belongs together. Another approach is to put UpdatePanel1+DropDownList and the Button in an outer UpdatePanel(with ChildrenAsTriggers=true). Or you could make `UpdatePanel2` [`UpdateMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) to conditional and update it from codebehind in the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event. Just a matter of preference.

Comment: @NickBork: OP wants to update the content of UpdatePanel2 (the Button's display style) from the SelectedIndexChanged event of a DropDownList in UpdatePanel1 (hence vice-versa). So i have defined an `AsyncPostBackTrigger ` for exact this requirement. And yes, you can update another UpdatePanel's content. You need to make it's `UpdateMode` conditional and call `UpdatePanel.Update()` from codebehind.

Comment: @NickBork - I am not updating content in panel1, panel1 is an example by Tim Schmelter, for me panel1 is just some filtering.  And you cannot just use `.Visible=true;` or `.Visible=false;` for the purpose I mainly stated - the filters (drop downs) are in an update panel.  The button isn't in an update panel, therefore Tim is right on, you cannot set the visibility of a server control like that in code behind in an async postback.

Comment: @nickbork, Tim's code mentioned above is correct. I have checked my side.

Answer (score 2):

this works :

```
gv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, "-44px");
```

to add the style

and

```
gv.Style.Remove("top");
```

to remove the style

Answer (score 1):

```
btnSaveLineItems.Style["display"] = "block";
```

Comment: It's a tested code. When you need to show the `Button`, set the `display` attribute to `block`.  That's it :)

Comment: No thats not it, the rendered html comes out as `<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSaveLineItems" value="Save" id="MainContent_btnSaveLineItems" title="Save changes?" style="border-color:#4B6C9E;border-style:Solid;display:none;" />` I have debugged my code.

Comment: Start with a sample application. and check with a `Button` only. Set the `Attribute` to block at `Form load` and set the `Display` to `none` in designer. Once the `Page loads` it will show you `Button`. I assume you have some other issue connected with this.

Comment: Its probably because my event is inside of an updatepanel and the button is outside of the updatepanel.  That is why this is happening...

Comment: Can you tell something ? which event?

Comment: did you read my post...the buttons should be enabled based on a selectedindexchanged event (drop down list).  That drop down list is inside of an updatepanel with asyncpostback.

Comment: All controls outside the Update Panel are not supposed to be updated. In case you want to update the Button Attributes, it is must to keep the button inside the Update Panel. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can Just add the class d-none by getting it class name and then remove the class d-none where you want to show the button.