# How get Html code with display:none tag

Tags: c#, html

I want get html with HttpWebRequest and parse it

I can do this but HttpWebRequest not return display:none tags

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125609/display-none-remove-style-for-asp-net-code-behind-not-working

Comment: thank you but i want get html  with HttpWebRequest and parse it , I can do this but HttpWebRequest not return display:none tags

Comment: What are you even talking about?  Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: @EhsanGh: `HttpWebRequest` doesn't filter markup based on styling.  Something else is wrong.  When something isn't working the way you expect, don't assume that something in .NET must be broken and that your code must be infallible.  That assumption will never get you far.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div id="displaynone" runat="server">   
displaynone.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
        var hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(my_url);
        var htmls_page_1 = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```